# Uncaught error "myApp" has not been registered. This can happpen if: *Metro (the local dev server) is running from the wrong folder. React Native

Tags: react-native

LOG  Running "myApp" with {"rootTag":11}
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "gasleet" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes